# Type trait on std::reference_wrapper<std::any>

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++17

`std::reference_wrapper` should be copy-constructible, regardless of the contained type (it's just a pointer inside). However, when asserting that using

```
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::any> >::value, "!");
```

Clang terminates with a compile error from inside the STL, while GCC reports no problems. This is not the case with other types (I tested `std::reference_wrapper<int>` and `std::any` directly).

I have an example showing compilation in GCC and Clang at https://godbolt.org/z/7YwkWb.

As far as I understand it, even if the type given to `std::is_copy_constructible` is not copy-constructible, it should just give a compile-time false, rather than failing compilation.
What is the problem here? Is that a compiler bug or am I missing something?

The compile error from Clang is:

```
In file included from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/type_traits:132:31: error: no member named 'value' in 'std::is_copy_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::any> >'
    : public conditional<_B1::value, _B2, _B1>::type
                         ~~~~~^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/any:170:17: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::any> >, std::is_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::any>, const std::reference_wrapper<std::any> &> >' requested here
      enable_if<__and_<is_copy_constructible<_Tp>,
                ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/any:175:5: note: in instantiation of template type alias '__any_constructible' requested here
    using __any_constructible_t =
    ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/any:181:56: note: in instantiation of template type alias '__any_constructible_t' requested here
              __any_constructible_t<_Tp, _ValueType&&> = true,
                                                       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/any:183:7: note: while substituting prior template arguments into non-type template parameter [with _ValueType = const std::reference_wrapper<std::any> &, _Tp = std::reference_wrapper<std::any>, _Mgr = std::any::_Manager_internal<std::reference_wrapper<std::any> >]
      any(_ValueType&& __value)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/type_traits:921:56: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'any' [with _ValueType = const std::reference_wrapper<std::any> &, _Tp = (no value), _Mgr = (no value), $3 = (no value), $4 = (no value)]
      : public __bool_constant<__is_constructible(_Tp, _Args...)>
                                                       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/type_traits:933:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::is_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::any>, const std::reference_wrapper<std::any> &>' requested here
    : public is_constructible<_Tp, const _Tp&>
             ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/type_traits:939:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__is_copy_constructible_impl<std::reference_wrapper<std::any>, true>' requested here
    : public __is_copy_constructible_impl<_Tp>
             ^
<source>:12:20: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::is_copy_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::any> >' requested here
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::any> >::value, "!");
                   ^
In file included from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/type_traits:137:31: error: no member named 'value' in 'std::is_copy_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::any> >'
    : public conditional<_B1::value, __and_<_B2, _B3, _Bn...>, _B1>::type
                         ~~~~~^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/any:192:27: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::any> >, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::any>, const std::reference_wrapper<std::any> &> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<std::reference_wrapper<std::any> > > >' requested here
              enable_if_t<__and_<is_copy_constructible<_Tp>,
                          ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/any:196:7: note: while substituting prior template arguments into non-type template parameter [with _ValueType = const std::reference_wrapper<std::any> &, _Tp = std::reference_wrapper<std::any>, _Mgr = std::any::_Manager_internal<std::reference_wrapper<std::any> >]
      any(_ValueType&& __value)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/type_traits:921:56: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'any' [with _ValueType = const std::reference_wrapper<std::any> &, _Tp = (no value), _Mgr = (no value), $3 = (no value)]
      : public __bool_constant<__is_constructible(_Tp, _Args...)>
                                                       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/type_traits:933:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::is_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::any>, const std::reference_wrapper<std::any> &>' requested here
    : public is_constructible<_Tp, const _Tp&>
             ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/type_traits:939:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__is_copy_constructible_impl<std::reference_wrapper<std::any>, true>' requested here
    : public __is_copy_constructible_impl<_Tp>
             ^
<source>:12:20: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::is_copy_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::any> >' requested here
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::any> >::value, "!");
                   ^
2 errors generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: Please include the compiler error in your question.

Comment: concerning the "...rather than failing compilation": The whole point of `static_assert` is to fail at compile time, if you just want to see the value, dont put it in a `static_assert`

Comment: user463035818: You're absolutely right. But the compilation in Clang does not fail because the `static_assert` fails. It also fails if I remove the `static_assert` or if I negate the argument. The issue is that there is an error while evaluating the (constexpr) argument to `static_assert`.

Comment: yes, I just think the `static_assert` is a bit of a red herring and your sentence is wrong/slightly misleading. If the type you give to `std::is_copy_constructible` is not copy-constructible, you will get a compile-time false, **and** the code will fail at compilation (because of the static assert)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you see clearly states at the top that `std::is_copy_constructible` doesn't have a `value` member for the specialization you check. Now, the types you pass don't violate the contract of `std::is_copy_constructible`, so there is no risk of undefined behavior.

Which means only one thing, it's not a compiler issue, but a standard library implementation issue. Clang uses the default installed standard library implementation, which on the system `godbolt` is running is `libstdc++` (the GNU implementation). This evidently causes the issue due to some possible soft incompatibility.

If you specify the `-stdlib=libc++` option (`libc++` is the LLVM implementation of the standard library) when building with Clang, then it accepts the code fine.

Comment: That makes sense. I hadn't thought about the STL. However: shouldn't Clang be able to compile with the GNU implementation of the standard library?

Comment: @ephimetheus - Usually. Both each standard library version is more tailored towards one compiler. Sometimes, it can cause issues, like you see.